# Return error message PHP

Tags: php

Well,

I have form to login in my **index.php** and in **login.php**
I check if there is an error.

I want return the message to Index.php and show the message by `$error_txt`

Below is my code:

**Index.php:**

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="user-input" /><br />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="user-input" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" id="user-submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white;"/><br />
<a href="register.php">Register</a>
<?php echo $error_txt; ?> <!-- --------- Here I Want show the error message -->
</form>
```

**Login.php:**

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $errors = 0;
            try
            {
                if(strlen($username) == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception ("The username is empty");
                }
                if(strlen($password) == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception ("The password is empty");
                }
                include ("web/config.php");
                $usernameTrueQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$password' LIMIT 1;");
                $usernameTrue = mysql_num_rows($usernameTrueQuery);
                if($usernameTrue == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception ("The username or password is incorrect");
                }
            } catch (Exception $loginError) {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-warning'>
              <strong>Error:</strong> ".$loginError->getMessage()."</div> \n";
              $errors = 1;
              $error_txt = $loginError->getMessage();
            }
            if($errors == 0)
            {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>
              <strong>Success</strong> Welcome {$username}!</div> \n";
            }
    }
    return $error_txt;
    header("Location: /index.php");
?>
```

thanks.. :)

Comment: Maybe instead of redirecting, you can just `include` the login form in the login page too, show it re-shows the form if there is an error. You can save the form itself in a separate file and include it both in index.php and login.php.

Comment: @GolezTrol good idiea, but I want some page login and its more code. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the error message in a [cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). However, this is also a bit ugly.

Slightly better: store it [in the session](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php). PHP can already maintain a session (and the session id in turn is stored in a cookie). By using the session, the message never needs to leave the server. However, this still may cause side effect, especially if the visitor has multiple tabs with different pages of your website open. They may at some time see the error on a page from which they didn't attempt to log in.

For a solution without 'remembering' the text somewhere, you shouldn't use a redirect at all. Just include the other page or a part of that is needed to display the form. If you could include the login form (or if you need to the entire index page), you can render the page including the error message without redirecting back to index.php.

You can also revert that principle by not posting to `login.php`, but to post to the index page itself. The page can check the posted data and only redirect to a success-page if logging in was successful.

Comment: Thank you very much, 
Session is good idea but maybe I use him later..
Thanks for help!!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show an error message on same page then either you have to use Ajax or submit form on same page (in your case it would be index.php)

Other way would be to pass error message through get parameter like **index.php?error=error-message-string** and then check whether error parameter is set or not and according to that display your message

Comment: It is unprofessional to show the GET parameter error..

No one can't do it by return and header ?